# GoDaddy IIS + Plesk + Web.Config = 500 Errors

Tags: iis, upload, web-config, plesk

We have migrated classic ASP sites to Plesk Parallels on GoDaddy. Because the server is now ASP.NET, we have needed to employ a web.config file.

A basic web.config file is fine enough for the site to run without errors, but whenever we attempt to modify this to raise the 200kb file upload limit (browser-based), the site either crashes or errors on >200kb upload.

Does anyone have any tips or experience with GoDaddy + Plesk + web.config files increasing the max file size? Even a known-working copy of a web.config file in this context would be great.

Sorry if this question is so pedestrian, but thanks in advance!

Comment: *"or errors on >200kb upload*" ... what's the error message?

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: It's just an error 500, generic

Comment: To get real error try to do same steps(upload file) from server. Or set in IIS show error details for non-localhost clients.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for other host providers other than GoDaddy but here is the solution in case you are looking for one:

Plesk > Virtual Directories > Directory Properties Tab > Scroll to ASP Settings and override the “Maximum size of entity body of an ASP request (KB)"

primesiteweb.com